# Firebase Cloud Functions: require('nodemailer') causes error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am trying to add email to a firebase cloud function. However, when ever I add the line:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

to index.js, code which previously deployed will no longer deploy. It reports that one of my functions had an error, but this can't be the case cause it works just fine with that function. Here is the full code, runs without the line just fine.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.routineKick = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 2 minutes')
  .timeZone('America/New_York')
  .onRun(context => {
     //kickMembers();
  }
);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing.  Please edit the question to run through the steps anyone could take to reproduce the issue.  If there's an error message, be sure to copy that into the question.  We need to be able to see what you see.

Comment: What is your Firebase plan? And have you completed your billing account?

Comment: Blaze. At this point I have run other functions sucessfully, they don't show up in my code sample because I cut everything out searching for the error.

Comment: @PeterWagstaff have you fixed the issue? If so, add it to an answer instead of editing it into your question, that way, if someone else has the issue it could be easier to find.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, there's no need to edit the question with you solution.  You can simply answer your own question and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution as a Community Wiki since this solution was shared by an edit to the question itself by the OP.

The problem is that the app was missing the nodemailer dependency. It can be fixed by doing the following:

In the package.JSON file, located at the functions folder, add under `dependencies` the following: `"nodemailer": "^6.4.3"` or whatever version you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using node mailer version of 6.7.0, In the "package.JSON" file, downgrade node version from 14 to 10 works for me

```
"engines": {
"node": "10"
},
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
"nodemailer": "^6.7.0"
},
```